# Ensure return type of templated generic parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I'm trying to make a compile time generics example. I've made it enforce that the methods exists, but I can't figure out how to enforce the return type:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class...> struct voider { using type = void; }
template<class... T> using void_t = typename voider<T...>::type;

template<class T, class = void> struct add_able : std::false_type {};
template<class T> struct add_able
< T, void_t < std::is_same < decltype(std::declval<T>().addOne()), void >,
              std::is_same < decltype(std::declval<T>().subOne()), void > > >
: std::true_type {};

class A { public: int addOne(); void subOne(); } // compiles and runs
class B { public: void addOne(int); void subOne(); } // fails
class C { public: void addOne(); void subOne(); } // compiles and runs as expected
class D { public: void subOne(); } // fails
```

This ensures that there is a `addOne()` and `subOne()` method but the return types are completely arbitrary.  How do I enforce this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::is_same<T>` is a type. Its instantiation will never fail (triggering a substitution failure) as you'd expect. You have to wrap it in a `std::enable_if` and read the value that `std::is_same<T>` returns by accessing a nested `::value` static member.

```
template<class T, class = void> struct add_able : std::false_type {};
template<class T> struct add_able
< T, void_t < typename std::enable_if<
//                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
           std::is_same < decltype(std::declval<T&>().addOne()), void >::value
//                                                                     ~~~~~~^
           && std::is_same < decltype(std::declval<T&>().subOne()), void >::value
//        ~^^~                                                            ~~~~~~^
              >::type
//             ~~~~~^
            >
>
: std::true_type {};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97ab4a409651c444)

Comment: @Czipperz you can shorten the syntax by means of  using `std::is_void` in place of `std::is_same<..., void>`

Comment: Nice.  Note that this also works without void_t: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd41f8a2c7b4bea2

Comment: @VaughnCato to be pedantic, you should use `std::enable_if<..., void_t<>>::type` (just in case `void_t<>` is not `void`, and the primary template takes `class = void_t<>`)